# basic_socket_acceptor interface changed in boost 1.66... is this a mistake?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I found that between boost 1.65 and boost 1.66 the interface of basic_socket_acceptor is different. Check it here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor.html

As you see at the end of the pages, the number of template parameters is different. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out they mentioned this in the [release info](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html), and one should add this define:

```
BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_OLD_SERVICES
```

And this will restore the number of parameters to two.

Comment: It also upgrades your code to the "deprecated" status. Make it a task to update the code to use the new interface so you don't run into stopping issues in future releases

Comment: @sehe Absolutely!